# Hypotheses for a two independent sample test.

Tags: probability, statistics

I came across a question that asks to perform a hypothesis testing on two independent samples on sample 1 (size=40) and sample 2 (size=30) to see if they differ by 0.5. What would be the null and the alternative hypotheses? And also what would the acceptance and the rejection region look like?

I have dealt with a numerous questions that simply asks if the two independent means are equal but this particular question really got me stuck.

Stats expert, could you please enlighten me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean a hypothesis test that the difference between the means in .5?
This could just be written as $H_0: |\mu_1-\mu_2|=.5 $  $ H_a: |\mu_1-\mu_2|\neq.5$. You would now need to find the distribution of $ |\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}| $, which would depend on how your data was originally distributed. If your sample is normal (probably too small a sample size to appeal to the central limit theorem) then the difference of two normals is normal and the absolute value of a normal is a folded normal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution). You would then reject if  $|\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}|> C_1$ or if  $|\bar{x_1}-\bar{x_2}|< C_2$ for some critical values $ C_1$ and $C_2 $. This is just the most immediate way to approach the problem to me though, I'm not certain if the test is UMP, another approach could be better. For example you could simply test   $H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2+.5 $ and $H_0: \mu_1+.5=\mu_2 $ as two separate tests in the typical two independent means are equal case that you are familiar with, but I believe there are some problems with this approach, specifically if you are looking for p-values.